# TypeError: Cannot call method 'finally' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have below script for `Angular promise`.I have chained `finally method` with `then` bale.But some time I am getting error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'finally' of undefined`.

Here is the script :

```
someSerivces.getSomeMethod(someData)
    .then(
        function(data) {
            //success
        },

        function(error) {
            // rejection
        }

    ).finally(function() {
        //script
    });
```

**GetSomeMethod :**

```
someSerivces.getSomeMethod = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        otherService.httpCall({...})
        .then(
                function(response) {
                  deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },

                function(response) {
                  deferred.reject(response);
                }

            );

        return deferred.promise;
      };
```

I know its because of promise is not available for chaining.So,it getting such error.How I can hanlded this error ? Or is there any other way to handled it?

How I can handled this exception?

Comment: Show us `getsomeMethod`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I have added generic script

Comment: You get this error *"sometimes"*? Anyway, from your code - this is not possible what you are describing.

Comment: What if the http call resulted in error  and does not return promise?

Comment: It doesn't even matter how http goes, because `getSomeMethod` returns promise *always*. So there is no way finally will be unavailable. So again - posted code can't result into error you describe.

Comment: Also [avoid the deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!